# Solr query for matching relational data and calculate as virtual field

Tags: solr, nested

I have documents as below structure:

```
"id":4005,
"hotel_id":"258",
"hotel_city_code":"DXB",
"hotel_name":"NAIA BREEZE HOTEL APARTMENT BY DAMAC",
"hotel_star":"5",
"room_adults_child":"2-0"
_childDocuments_: [
    {
        map_date_rate:[
            {date:0901, rate:207.09},
            {date:0814, rate:207.09},
            {date:0815, rate:159.50},
            {date:0816, rate:200.00},
            {date:0820, rate:207.09},
            {date:0809, rate:207.09},
            {date:0825, rate:207.09},
            {date:0808, rate:207.09},
            {date:0818, rate:207.09},
            {date:0830, rate:207.09}
        ]
    }
]
```

how to write a query to find all documents having below conditions:

```
room_adults_child: 2-0
map_date_rate.date:(0814 AND 0815 AND 0816)
```

then select below fields of those documents:

```
id, 
hotel_id,
room_rates:sum(map_date_rate.rate)
```

**room_rates** in above is a virtual field that will be sum of rates of searched dates : (207.09 + 159.50 + 200.00) = 566.59

Thank you for any help.